# Ionic 4 Browser PHP Force Clearing Cache

Tags: javascript, php, html, ionic-framework

I have an App made with Ionic 4 and compiled for the browser. The problem is that when I do an update and upload it to the server, to see the changes the client has to clear the cache or access incognito mode.

I've traied changing the version of package.json, but doesn't works.

How can I solve that?

EDIT: I have tried to put ?ver = 1.0 in the index.html .js paths and it works, now the PHP file is missing, but I don't know how to do it like

Comment: what do you mean by `now the PHP file is missing`?

Comment: @WaleedJubeh (I made changes to some variables in the PHP file that connects the Ionic app with the MySQL database). I think the PHP file is stored in Cache, and it is not updated

Comment: The PHP file is not stored in the cache, every time the server calls the file directly. but I need to mention that if you add for example ?ver=1 then for the next version it should be an un-used value like: ?ver=2, ?ver=3..., and I recommend making them incremental.

Comment: You need to add?ver for both CSS and js files.

Comment: Yes heat, in the .js I add? Ver = 1, in the next update? Ver = 2 ... But one of the pages of my ionic app, takes the data from the DB with PHP, and right now I see the page Ionic app blank (because I changed the names of the PHP variables and I think it tries to get the old names)

Comment: I if I go into incognito mode, I see all the data correctly

Comment: ok, could you click Ctrl + U to see if '?ver' prefix is changed.

Comment: I changed the prefix? see in the index.html of the App, I have done Ctrl + U in the Tab (internal page of the App) and the prefixes do not appear

Comment: but if I inspect element in the internal page,  the prefixes wich i've changed appear with ?ver=1. But there are lots of .js withous the prefix

Comment: did you deploy your work to a specific domain? if so, please provide, this could be useful to track

Comment: `But there are lots of .js withous the prefix ` are these files build results?

Comment: Yes, these files are build results

Comment: and you added the prefix to them but they are not appeared?